# Заполнение персональных данных при регистрации аккаунта разработчика в Google Play

Tags: google-play

При регистрации аккаунта разработчика в Google Play был оплачен регистрационный сбор через турецкий счет. При заполнении персональных данных нужно так же указывать данные турецкого паспорта или можно по российскому?